# Library to parse a bind 9.x zone file in Java?

Tags: java, file, parsing, bind, zone

Is there anything out there that already does this?

I looking for something that will help me get a bind zone file loaded into java objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`dnsjava`](http://www.dnsjava.org/) library has a zone file parser - specifically you need the `org.xbill.DNS.Master` class.